# Convergence of a series if $(n\cdot a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is increasing.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a non negative sequence.

Also, Let $(n\cdot a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be increasing, and $a_1>0$.

Prove/disprove: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n} = \infty$.

I was trying to find counterexamples, but I couldn't find any.
Then I was trying to prove it by contradiction, but I got stuck. This is what I tried to do:

Assume in contradiction that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n<\infty$.
So it holds that $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$.
Therefore $\lim_{n\to \infty}n\cdot a_n=\infty\cdot 0=0$.
That's a contradiction since the sequence is increasing and $a_1>0$.

But I was wrong since $\infty\cdot0$ is undefined.

I have no intuition at this point, can I get a hint?

Comment: If $c_n = n a_n,$ then $a_n = \dfrac{c_n}{n}.$ The point being is that $c_n$ is any increasing function. Since $c_n$ is increasing, then $c_n \geq c_1,$ and $a_n \geq \dfrac{c_1}{n}.$

Comment: @WillM. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can write $(n+1)a_{n+1}\geq na_{n}$ and therefore $a_{n+1}\geq \frac{n}{n+1}a_n$. Iterate this and get

$$
a_{n+1} \geq \frac{n}{n+1} \frac{n-1}{n}\ldots\frac{1}{2}a_1 =\frac{a_1}{n+1},
$$
and therefore
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n \geq a_1 \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since you always have $na_n\geqslant a_1$, you have $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):a_n\geqslant\frac{a_1}n$, and therefore $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\infty$.